# Xcode target compiled with optimization

Tags: xcode, gcc

I am seeing following warning message, when I build target ABC.

ABC was compiled with optimization - stepping may behave oddly; variables may not be available.

I have made sure about optimization (GCC_OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL = 0), but still build is showing above message.

How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

In Xcode go to Product > Scheme > Edit Scheme...

and change the Build Configuration from "Release" to "Debug" (within the "Run" menu under "Info").

Comment: Thanks for help, but it didn't work. I am still seeing same warning message.

Answer (score 1):

Xcode generally throws this type of error when *compiler optimisation level is set other than None* in debug mode. To do it follow below steps.

Step 1: Go to your build settings

Step 2: Search for ***SWIFT_OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL***

Step 3: Go to Optimization level in debug mode.

Step 4: Change it into None[-Onone].

[image]

Comment: This did not work for me, as None was already selected when the crash happened.

Answer (score 0):

Try turning off the 'Debug Executable' in scheme settings. But I do not know if this is recommended.